# c# keeps calculating something different then what it should

Tags: c#

At the bottom I have the calculation(num1 = num1 + (r[i] * Math.Pow(10, anz1 - i - 1)). Both components are correct but together it just makes no sense. Can anyone help me please?

```
    Console.Write("Enter your calculation: ");
    string r = Console.ReadLine();
    double num1 = 0;
    int anz1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < r.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(r[i]))
        {
            anz1++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }



    for (int i = 0; i < anz1; i++)
    {
        num1 = num1 + (r[i] * Math.Pow(10, anz1 - i - 1));
        Console.WriteLine(num1);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please clarify what the actual problem is, i.e. what is the expected output, and what is the actual output? Also, it's not clear what you mean by "components".

Comment: what do you expect to get, what did you get?, please provide more info

Comment: You try multiplying char r[i] with double.

Comment: Could you please add an example of input X should result in output Y but it's giving me output Z (multiple examples would be even better). From the code it looks like you're trying to make something that reverses the digits and stores that in a number. So my assumption is that the problem is in the fact that you use r[i] this is a character and the compiler is smart enough to see it needs to convert this into an int. However it does this based on the character codes: http://www.asciitable.com/. Which means that the charater `'0'` has an int value of `60`.

Comment: My string is 12345 So r[i] is 1 at first. I multiply it with Math.Pow etc. which is 10^5. But in some way c# calculates 4900000.

Comment: r[i] is not 1 actually. See @Knoop comment.

Comment: z1 = Convert.ToInt32(r[i].ToString()); Thanks for your help! I managed to solve the problem with this command. Not that good of a solution but it works!

Answer (score 3):

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < anz1; i++)
{
    num1 = num1 + (r[i] * Math.Pow(10, anz1 - i - 1));
    Console.WriteLine(num1);
}
```

You multiply by the ASCII-Value of `char` `r[i]`:
Example:
char **'0'** convert to number **48** in ASCII(decimal)
char **'2'** convert to number **50** in ASCII(decimal)
....
[Wiki about ASCII-Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)

You should `.Parse()` `Char` to an `Integer` before any numeric calculation:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < anz1; i++)
{
    int intR = int.Parse(r[i].ToString());

    num1 = num1 + (intR * Math.Pow(10, anz1 - i - 1));
    Console.WriteLine(num1);
 }
```

More Infos: [Microsoft Docs - How to: Convert a String to a Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number)

Comment: "ASCII-Value": The generic term is "character code". .NET uses the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set. I have not encountered any programming language that uses the ASCII character set.